# A VRP formulation where customer i needs to be visited before customer j?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, integer-programming, discrete-optimization

The title explains the problem more or less. I am looking for literature for a specific constraint, where a customer $i$ needs to be visited before another costumer $j$ can be visited.
Are there any such formulation. I have looked at a modification to the VRPTW problem as an example.

Comment: search for "precedence constraints"